# VHDL flip-flop reset different than 0

Tags: initialization, vhdl, reset, flip-flop

is any possibility to reset flip-flop vector to different value than all 0?
something like:

```
PROCESS (clk)
    BEGIN
        IF RISING_EDGE(clk) THEN
            IF rst = '1' THEN
                ff <= INPUT_VALUE;
...
```

This don't survive synthesis.
I want to get the value to ff only when resetting, then I'm changing it - it works as a counter with first value set from input.

Comment: This should be synthesizable because it looks like a synchronous load. Please give a full example and specify the synthesis tool you are using.

Comment: The full process is 
`code PROCESS (clk)
BEGIN
 IF RISING_EDGE(clk) THEN
  IF rst = '1' THEN
   iv_reg <= iv;
  ELSE
   IF input_change = '1' THEN
     iv_reg <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( UNSIGNED( iv_reg ) + 1 );
    ELSE
     iv_reg <= iv_reg;
   END IF;
  END IF;
 END IF;
END PROCESS; `
Synthesized by XST

Comment: Functionally, it looks perfect. What do you mean by doesn't "survive synthesis"?

Comment: I'd make two changes, though: i) If you use `ELSIF` instead of `ELSE IF` you need one less `END IF` which just neatens things up. ii) you never ever need lines line this in a sequential process: `ELSE iv_reg <= iv_reg;`. It's not wrong, but it is unnecessary, because if you don't assign to `iv_reg` it will remember its previous state - precisely the behaviour you want in a sequential process. See: http://www.edaplayground.com/x/2RDr

Comment: Thanks for advices, when I use it without rest of the design, it works fine. So I add extra signal for loading and it's ok.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor One has to be careful with an `elsif` on a reset condition.  Depending upon the synthesizer, it may not infer a preset or clear.  Our coding standard requires resets be implemented as a single `if` with an `else`, and all other logic nested in the `else` statement.  We have seen synthesizers in the past create priority encoders and other logic on the D input, rather than use the preset or clear available, when using `elsif`.

Comment: @PlayDough Thanks for your comment. That's interesting. So, you're trying to persuade your synthesiser to use a flop with a synchronous reset input and it isn't doing so, right? Which synthesisers are you talking about?

Comment: @MatthewTaylor My experience was initially with Autologic and early version of Ambit.  And I saw similar issues with ISE (notably with synchronous sets--despite being available in the technology).  The other issue with the if/elsif/else is that you may not make use of both the synchronous set and clear unless ordered properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about implementing a normal reset and then use **load** signal to set the counter to something else? This to me would be the standard way.

Answer (score 0):

The following is an amusing answer that would actually work:

1) Determine the bit pattern of the value that it should be initialized to.

2) For every bit that should be a 1, put a not gate on that line before and after the flip-flop.

Now the initial state after the reset pin is the state you want.

Comment: Usually the synthesis tool does such things for you. But that on the side, this is a 2 year old question. I doubt the asker still has his/her problem..